# flash_set, flash_get in PHP?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails

so i got told in this question:
[PHP/Javascript passing message to another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291413/php-javascript-passing-message-to-another-page)

to use flash_set and flash_get, concept called "Rails flash".. Now can you use them in php those function? I can really find them in php library site, so im not sure..

Comment: Retagged as the question really has nothing to with "Flash" the technology.

Answer (score 2):

You can store the messages you want to flash on the next page request in the $_SESSION. I don't know exactly how the methods work in rails but hopefully these two functions can be of use:

```
function flash_get()
{
    // If there are any messages in the queue
    if(isset($_SESSION['flashMessages']))
    {
        // Fetch the message queue
        $messages = $_SESSION['flashMessages'];

        // Empty out the message queue
        unset($_SESSION['flashMessages']);

        return $messages;
    }

    // No messages so just return an empty array
    return array();
}

function flash_set($message)
{
    // If the queue is currently empty we need to create an array
    if(!isset($_SESSION['flashMessages'])) {
        $_SESSION['flashMessages'] = array();
    }

    // Fetch the current list of messages and append the new one to the end
    $messages = $_SESSION['flashMessages'];
    $messages[] = $message;

    // Store the message queue back in the session
    $_SESSION['flashMessages'] = $messages;
}
```

Just call flash_set() with the message you want to store and flash_get() will give you that array back and flush the queue on a later page request.

You'll have to make sure as well that you call [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) with every page request for these methods to work.

Comment: But this is just like storing with normal session, but you did it to functions?

Comment: it's not quite that simple, as this won't distinguish between messages added on a previous page and those added earlier in the current page, you'll need to store 'current' and 'previous' separately, and on page-load, swap them over. Zend Framework's FlashMessenger might be helpful to look at.

Comment: This by no means a complete solution, it's 2 short methods. I use the Zend Framework version as well but since he never mentioned anything about a framework I didn't feel it was necessary to suggest he use one just to get some simple functionality.

Comment: @Azzyh Yes, it's just storing some strings in the session, but instead of copying and pasting the 5 lines of code everywhere you can just call the functions. As far as I know, there is no build in way to do this. As Greg mentioned though, Zend Framework has a solution for this problem which is much better then the 2 functions I presented. If you want to work with a framework, you might consider that.

Answer (score 2):

There's no a built-in function in PHP to achieve this, but if you use some frameworks as CakePHP (which is inspired on rails), you'll find it quite simple:

```
// In the controller
$this->Session->setFlash('message to flash');

// In the view
$session->flash();
```

I bet some other frameworks have this covered.