# Sending and showing messages from one PHP script to another

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have the following code in a page (index.php), it's composed by just two DIVs, one on the left side (#leftDIV), which contains a form and another DIV (#messages) which will receive error messages, and another DIV (#mapAJAX) on the right side, which contains a PHP script that should send error messages to that #messages DIV.

```
<div id="leftDIV">
  <form method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
    ...
    Some code here
    ...
    <input type=button value="Cercar" onclick="search();"/>
    <input type=reset value="Esborrar" />
  </form>
  <div id="messages">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div id="mapAJAX"></div>
```

Once the form is submitted a Javascript function is called, it'll create a XMLHttpRequest object to load a PHP script in the right side, the idea is to reload only the content on the right side every time the form is submitted. Inside this new script (map.php) I do a search in a database and load the results in a map inside this same right DIV.

If any problems occur, I want to show the error inside the #messages DIV I mentioned earlier, but I have no idea how to send those messages to that DIV from the map.php script. Just searching for any DOM element with the #messages id won't work, because that script doesn't have ready access to the left DIV.

I have read this post:

[PHP/Javascript passing message to another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291413/php-javascript-passing-message-to-another-page)

But I don't know how to trigger the showing of the messages, once a new one is generated. So what can I do?

Also feel free to suggest a new title, I'm not sure mine fully describes the problem I'm exposing.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:** As requested, here is the AJAX code found inside the index.php file. This function is called after search() has done a couple checks on the form values. It uses a file called AJAX.js to ease the creation of the XMLHttpRequest.

```
function loadMap(ciutat, tipusCuina){
  var div = document.getElementById("mapAJAX");
  var oXMLHttpRequest = createXMLHttpRequestObject();
  var url = "mapa.php?ciutat=" + ciutat + "&tipusCuina=" + tipusCuina;

  oXMLHttpRequest.open('GET', url);
  oXMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(oXMLHttpRequest.readyState == 4){
      if(oXMLHttpRequest.status == 200){
        div.innerHTML = oXMLHttpRequest.responseText;
      }
      else{
        alert("Hi ha hagut un problema amb la recepcio del mapa.");
      }
    }
  }

  oXMLHttpRequest.send(null);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could show us your AJAX, you'll just have to display the `reponseText` inside the `innerHTML` of your div it seems, provided you are not using iframes or frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP cannot really operate on your DOM in this way. You are using Javascript to get the results of a PHP script. So the next step is to put that result into a div in your DOM. You will do this also with Javascript, not PHP. Are you working with a Javascript library like JQuery or Mootools? If so, this is a very simple task.

Comment: Hi, I'm not using any library. It's a college assignement to work with PHP, the AJAX and Javascript elements are just an extra I have added, to stop all the page from reloading.

Comment: Well, it sounds like you've got the PHP part figured out. If you don't want the page to reload, you'll mostly be working with Javascript from this point. I'd recommend using one of those libraries. They will make DOM manipulation much easier.

Comment: Up to this point, with my limited knowledge I only see two options, move all the PHP code (except for the map loading part) to the same file, since all the messages can come only from errors from user input  or database queries results, or use a library as you suggest. If I choose to use JQuery for example, what should I look for? I have never used it before. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know JQuery well either (I usually use Mootools) but I think you'd want: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/ for making Ajax request and http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/ for DOM manipulation.